# Yolov5/OpenCV - Estimate the real Distance from Object to Object

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, yolov5

im trying to solve the Problem, to estimate the real Distance between two Objects. I saw that there are some articles about image processing and calculating with Pixels, but thats not the thing i wanted. There are some marker based Calculation, where you get the known length of an Object and build a whole coordinate System from that known variable. Are there any Github Repos to build from that project? Or are there any Ideas, how to calculate AI based the real Distance betweeen Objects?

Thank you

Comment: A single 2D image does not contain depth information. You can obtain a rough estimate of the distance to the camera by guessing the real size of the object (but what about adult vs. child ?) From the distances to two objects and the positions on the 2D image, you can infer a very approximate distance by simple geometry. You also need to assume a certain focal length of the lens.

Comment: there are some DNN based depth estimators like MonoDepth, MIDAS and others. From depth you can estimate the 3D position relative to the camera. From that you know 3D positions of your objects and you can measure distances. But I doubt these pretrained 3D estimators are very accurate if you don't train them yourself for your camera, perspective and use-case. I often use ground plane assumption for 3D measurements with some good results.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but thats not the actual Length, if I would do that right?

Comment: @Micka does the MonoDepth and MIDAS work with an nvidia Jetson nano? So I want to calculate for example the length of an Parking Lot. Is that possible with the Jetson nano and a IMX219 camera?

Comment: @Arthi those DNNs are quite expensive, but if you need very low fps it should be possible to use the DNNs. BUT as said, I fear they aren't very accurate.

Comment: A single 2D image does not contain depth information. For an precise solution, calibrated stereoscopy or 3D cameras.

Comment: @Micka what do you mean by quite expensive?

Comment: @YvesDaoust so you can't get the actual distance by a single Camera?

Comment: @Arthi expensive = a lot of operations needed for one forward path through the network, so you would need very fast hardware to reach a high fps.

Comment: @Micka oh okay, i think the Jetson nano is quite good but not good enough for those Operations... is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Can you measure a car by just looking at it ?

Comment: no thats why i thought to use a circle based marker to get a known size and get the distortion from the Image to calculate the real size. But I don't know how to do that. My Method seems like you wrote before with the focal length of the lens @YvesDaoust

Comment: "i thought to...": you should have asked that question instead.